# CURDATE() com dia e hora

Tags: mysql, data

Em MySQL tenho uma tabela com campo tipo DATETIME, com esse valor: `2019-08-01 15:30:00`

Para controle, hoje é dia 01/08/2019 15:05:00

Quero fazer uma consulta que só mostra se a data no banco de dados for menor igual a  data atual, então fiz isso:

```
WHERE DATE(noticia.dia) <= CURDATE()
```

Mas ele está ignorando a hora, levando apenas em consideração o dia e mostrando no resultado a data `2019-08-01 15:30:00`, onde erro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `CURDATE` retorna apenas a data, sem hora, então sua condição está considerando `00:00:00`, que já passou. Você pode usar `NOW()`. A função `DATE` que você usou também está removendo a hora do outro lado, então a solução seria:

```
WHERE noticia.dia <= NOW()
```